# How to Place 10,000,000 Marker or PolyLine In Google Maps For JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-maps-markers

I want to show 10,000,000 location data(Telecom Data, Card Usage History and so on) to the user.

I chose Google Maps as a way of displaying it.

However, an error occurred when 100,000 markers were placed.

How can I display a lot of data without using Cluster Marker?

The reason why we don't use cluster markers is because we need to make it clear that all the data that came into the program was in a particular location at a particular time.

Comment: Why on Earth would you possible wish to display 10million markers on a map at once? The physical memory and processing required would be ridiculous - what is wrong with MarkerClusterer?

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/deckgl-points for an example usage of Google Maps and deckgl.

Comment: The reason why we don't use cluster markers is because we need to make it clear that all the data that came into the program was in a particular location at a particular time.

Answer (score 1):

Using native Google Maps API objects will cause the client browser to fail.

[Deck.gl](https://deck.gl/) is a great alternative to this kind of task as it uses a layer of WebGL to render the additional objects. I have tried it with over 500k objects and it ran smoothly. Give it a try.

Comment: All right, I'll try.